# How to iterate in a chef elb template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

I have a chef ruby elb template and i am not a ruby dev:

How do i iterate over the below?

```
for iter in node["cpu"]["total"].lentgh do
   server unix:/tmp/aiohttp_<%= iter %>.sock fail_timeout=0;
end
```

I want one line per cpu core e.g. 1,2,3,4

```
server unix:/tmp/aiohttp_0.sock fail_timeout=0;
server unix:/tmp/aiohttp_1.sock fail_timeout=0;
server unix:/tmp/aiohttp_2.sock fail_timeout=0;
server unix:/tmp/aiohttp_3.sock fail_timeout=0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `<% %>` tags for structural stuff like loops in Erb, or more often `<%- -%>` which also trims whitespace on otherwise blank lines. While `for` loops are a thing in Ruby, they are very much not recommended and idiomatic Ruby uses iterator methods instead. For "do it X times" that would be the `Numeric#times` method. Also the `total` key is just a number, so you can't use `.length` like that.

```
<%- node["cpu"]["total"].times do |i| -%>
server unix:/tmp/aiohttp_<%= i %>.sock fail_timeout=0;
<%- end -%>
```

You